# Singleton in current thread

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I have my singleton as below:

```
public class CurrentSingleton
{
    private static CurrentSingleton uniqueInstance = null;
    private static object syncRoot = new Object();
    private CurrentSingleton() { }

    public static CurrentSingleton getInstance()
    {
        if (uniqueInstance == null)
        {
            lock (syncRoot)
            {
                if (uniqueInstance == null)
                    uniqueInstance = new CurrentSingleton();
            }
        }
        return uniqueInstance;
    }
}
```

I would like check, if I will have two thread, are there two different singletons? I think, I shall have two different singletons (with different references), so what I'm doing:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int currentCounter = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            cs1 = null;
            cs2 = null;

            Thread ct1 = new Thread(cfun1);
            Thread ct2 = new Thread(cfun2);
            ct1.Start();
            ct2.Start(); 
            if (cs1 == cs2) currentCounter++;
        }
        Console.WriteLine(currentCounter);
        Console.Read();

    }

    static CurrentSingleton cs1;
    static CurrentSingleton cs2;

    static void cfun1()
    {
        cs1 = CurrentSingleton.getInstance();
    }

    static void cfun2()
    {
        cs2 = CurrentSingleton.getInstance();
    }
}
```

I suppose that I should got `currentCounter = 0` (in this case every two singleton are different - because are creating by other threrad). Unfortunately, I got for example `currentCounter = 70`  so in 70 cases I have the same singletons... Could you tell me why?

Answer (score 14):

> I would like check, if I will have two thread, are there two different singletons

No, there are not.  A `static` field is shared across each entire `AppDomain`, not each thread.

If you want to have separate values per thread, I'd recommend using [`ThreadLocal<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642243%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to store the backing data, as this will provide a nice wrapper for per-thread data.

Also, in C#, it's typically better to implement a lazy singleton via `Lazy<T>` instead of via double checked locking.  This would look like:

```
public sealed class CurrentSingleton // Seal your singletons if possible
{
    private static Lazy<CurrentSingleton> uniqueInstance = new Lazy<CurrentSingleton>(() => new CurrentSingleton());
    private CurrentSingleton() { }

    public static CurrentSingleton Instance  // use a property, since this is C#...
    {
        get { return uniqueInstance.Value; }
    }
}
```

To make a class that provides one instance per thread, you could use:

```
public sealed class InstancePerThread
{
    private static ThreadLocal<InstancePerThread> instances = new ThreadLocal<InstancePerThread>(() => new InstancePerThread());

    private InstancePerThread() {}
    public static InstancePerThread Instance
    {
        get { return instances.Value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't know about `ThreadLocal<T>`. It is probably better to use that then `[ThreadStatic]`.

Comment: @TimothyShields Yes, it's a nicer abstraction.  You can clean up after yourself, and the initialization is far better.

Comment: @Reed Copsey Using your class I have currentCounter = 13 or currentCounter = 18 . So in some cases still we have the same instances... It is not good, isn't ?

Comment: @makcis This will still use the same instance.  As I said, you'd need to use `ThreadLocal<T>` if you want to avoid using the same instances.

Answer (score 4):

By default, a `static` field is a single instance shared by all threads that access it.

You should take a look at the [`[ThreadStatic]` attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threadstaticattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Apply it to a `static` field to make it have a distinct instance for each thread that accesses it.

Comment: `[ThreadStatic]` works, but be aware that there are odd initialization issues (field initializers only work on the first thread that accesses), and there's no clean way to handle cleanup if you need disposal of the instances.

Comment: I added [ThreadStatic] before variable static CurrentSingleton cs1; and static CurrentSingleton cs2;. Now I'm getting currentCounter = 100 so in every case I have the same instance...It is still wrong

Comment: @makcis You'd need it inside of the CurrentSingleton class, not the variables you're setting.

Answer (score 1):

No matter what you do you are never going to get **currentCounter = 0**.
Because we are forgetting the the fact that **application/C# code** is also running in some thread and there are some priorities set by C# to run the code. If you debug the code by putting break points in Main method and CurrentSingleton you will notice that. By the time you reach and create the new Object for CurrentSingleton, for loop may be iteration 3 or 4 or any number. Iterations are fast and code is comparing null values and Object or Object and null value. And I think this is the catch.

[Reed](https://stackoverflow.com/users/65358/reed-copsey) has got point static will always be shared hence you need to change your code in following way

```
  public class CurrentSingleton
  {
    [ThreadStatic]
    private static CurrentSingleton uniqueInstance = null;
    private static object syncRoot = new Object();
    private CurrentSingleton() { }

    public static CurrentSingleton getInstance()
    {
        if (uniqueInstance == null)
            uniqueInstance = new CurrentSingleton();

        return uniqueInstance;
    }
}
```

And as per analysis you are getting two different objects at 70th iteration but, that is something just mismatch may be null and Object or Object and null. To get successful two different object you need to use [ThreadStatic]

Comment: There's no need to lock when using `[ThreadStatic]`, as there's no possible way for 2 threads to have resource contention on that resource...

Comment: I corrected the code. I just put my analysis what I find while debugging. Please correct me in case I am wrong.

Comment: You only need 1 null check, too - not 2 of them.

Answer (score 0):

Use of a locking object ensures that only one value gets created; you can verify this by putting some logging in your `CurrentSingleton` constructor.

However, I think there's a small gap in your logic: imagine that two threads simultaneously call this method, while `uniqueInstance` is null.  Both will evaluate the `= null` clause, and advance to the locking.  One will win, lock on `syncRoot`, and initialize `uniqueInstance`.  When the `lock` block ends, the other will get its own lock, and initialize `uniqueInstance` again.

You need to lock on `syncRoot` before even testing whether `uniqueInstance` is null.

Comment: There's a separate check inside of the lock, so that will actually work in (the microsoft CLR's implementation of) the .NET memory model.  Granted, it theoretically needs memory barriers in place to be correct, but double checked locking is "mostly" okay.