# c# can the same file writer singleton be used to write to multiple files at the same time

Tags: c#, multithreading, file, io, thread-safety

For instance, Can I make a singleton that writes to files and then use this in multiple threads to write to different files at the same time? Or is there some unwanted side effect I'm not thinking about? This is difficult to test out every scenario in a demo app so was hoping for some guidance. The Singleton File writer looks like this.

```
       public sealed class CustomFileWriter
       {
         private static CustomFileWriter(){}

         public static CustomFileWriter Instance
         {
                    get
                    {
                        lock (padlock)
                        {
                            if (instance == null)
                            {
                                instance = new CustomFileWriter();
                            }
                            return instance;
                        }
                    }
         }
         WriteToFile(string fileName, string contents)
         {
          // other business logic goes here that is not specific to the question.
          File.AppendAllText(fileName, contents)
         }
       }
```

Comment: There is no reason for that to exist; you should use `File` directly.

Comment: @SLaks There is some business logic that edits the file contents depending on which file it is going to. This is going to be used by multiple developers that don't need to worry about the text file format, just their contents

Comment: Does the order of which these multi-threaded writes occur matter?

Comment: @RonBeyer they do not care about order (each file is independent). but there are multiple UDP threads that will write different files and each call this singleton, sometimes at the same time

Comment: The problem this approach has is that Thread A will be blocked by Thread B even though they write to different files. If you want to do something like this, I would consider making the singleton ["thread-static"](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/overview-of-threadstatic-attribute-in-c-sharp/) so that the class is singleton-per-thread instead of the entire app domain.

Comment: See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22719596/singleton-in-current-thread

Comment: @RonBeyer Would using File.AppendAllText, be thread blocking as well? It is a static class

Comment: Only for the current thread, it is a blocking call, but it doesn't block other calls to it. All `AppendAllText` does is creates a `StreamWriter` and writes the text to the stream in a `using` block. You can see the code [on the reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/file.cs,4ff1446b33bdfb6b).

Comment: @RonBeyer Great, so creating new streams at the same time is possible? If so, I'll just change from a singleton to allow multiple instances

Comment: Yes, multiple streams can be created/used at the same time, the world would be a dark place if they couldn't be...